How do you describe a light wordline using affine parameter?
One can parametrize wordline of objects with nonzero mass in spacetime using $x^\alpha(\tau)=(ct(\tau), x(\tau), y(\tau), z(\tau))$ where $\tau$ is object's proper time.
I learned that wordline of a light beam cannot be parametrized this way because photons does not feel lapse in proper time. Instead of proper time, one uses some affine parameter $\lambda=a\tau+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are some constants. I think light's trajectory can be described by $x^\alpha(\lambda)=(ct(\lambda), x(\lambda), y(\lambda), z(\lambda))$. Also, I read in this answer that $x^\alpha(\tau)$ will return the same value for all $\tau$.
I am struggling to understand how it works and I would appreciate any explicit examples of such $x^\alpha(\lambda)$, preferably in flat spacetime.

In flat space time wouldn't you just use $t$ ?

@ProbRob You mean using coordinate time as an affine parameter?

That is normally how light wordlines are drawn on spacetime diagrams.

Here's an explicit way to construct a light worldline in special relativity (assuming flat spacetime), using spherical coordinates.
Consider the following world line, parameterized by the affine parameter $\lambda$:
\begin{align*}
x &= \int r\cos\theta\cos\phi\ \mathrm{d} \lambda\\
y &= \int r\cos\theta\sin\phi\ \mathrm{d} \lambda\\
z &= \int r\sin\theta\ \mathrm{d} \lambda\\
ct &= \int r\ \mathrm{d}\lambda
\end{align*}
Note that for now we assume $r,\theta,\phi$ may depend in any way on $\lambda$. As we will presently demonstrate, this world line still satisfies the condition of being a null curve.
Proof that this is a null curve:
A null curve with coordinates $x^{\mu}$ is defined in special relativity as one in which
$$ \eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\mu}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} \frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\nu}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = 0 $$
Which in our case translates to:
$$ \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2-
c^2\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 = 0 $$
Calculating the derivatives squared is straightforward:
\begin{align*}
  \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 &= r^2\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi & \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 &= r^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi \\
  \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 &= r^2\sin^2\theta & c^2\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 &= r^2
\end{align*}
So we get:
\begin{align*}
\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\mu}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} \frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\nu}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}&=
r^2\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi + r^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + 
r^2\sin^2\theta - r^2 \\ 
&= r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta - r^2\\
&= r^2 - r^2 \\
 &= 0 
\end{align*}
Which proves that this is a null curve.
Now, null curves for light in flat spacetime must correspond to straight lines, because there's no curvature that can bend the light by assumption. This means that this curve must also satisfy the geodesic equation, which in SR is:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda ^2} = 0 $$
Looking at the derivatives we computed $\large \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}$, we see that this condition implies all five functions $\sin\theta$, $\sin\phi$,$\cos\theta$, $\cos\phi$, $r$, cannot depend on $\lambda$. For if any one of them depended on $\lambda$, their derivative in $\lambda$ would not vanish, contradicting the above condition for being a geodesic.
This means that we can integrate the derivatives $\large \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}$ with respect to $\lambda$ to recover the worldline. Doing that, we see that all four coordinates of the curve take the form:
$$ x^\mu = x^\mu|_{\lambda=0} + \lambda\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d} x^\mu}{\mathrm{d} \lambda}  $$
Which we can write more explicitly, as:
\begin{align*}
x &=  x_0 + \lambda r\cos\theta\cos\phi\  \\
y &=  y_0 + \lambda r\cos\theta\sin\phi\  \\
z &=  z_0 + \lambda r\sin\theta\  \\
ct &= ct_0 + \lambda r 
\end{align*}
Which as expected, simply correspond to the motion of a light ray along a straight line, with some constant projection angles $\theta$ and $\phi$.

References: this answer is based on my solution of exercise 1.13. from the book "Problem Book In Relativity and Gravitation", Alan P. Lightman, William H. Press, Richard H. Price, Saul A. Teukolsky

Ok I think I read your solution too quickly. You’re saying you want to impose the condition of the geodesic equation on the above curve. I read that part as you asserting that it already satisfies the geodesic equation.

@peek-a-boo It's fine! I appreciate you taking the time to read my answer. If you have any other concerns, feel free to share.

Thanks for the example! I wonder if there exist some constants $a,b$ such that $x^\mu\left(\frac{\lambda-b}{a}\right)$ is undefined or returns the same value for all values of $\lambda$. I am trying to understand what's preventing one from parameterizing the path with proper time.

@weeab00 Recall that $\gamma = \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau = (1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$. But for light $v=c$ and $\gamma$ is not defined! For massive particles, the tangent of a world line is the four velocity $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{ \mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{ \mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{ \mathrm{d}\tau} = \gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{ \mathrm{d}t} $$ But again, you can't define $\gamma$ for light, hence no tangent to a world line parameterized by it, hence no world line parameterized by $\tau$ for light! :)

Thanks again. I think I can see how affine parameter is motivated in the first place. Light's wordline satisfies $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=c^2d\tau^2=0$ since $d\tau=0$. So, after introducing a parameter $\lambda$, divide by $(d\lambda)^2$ on both sides, $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}=0$. This is the equation light wordlines must satisfy.

@weeab00 Exactly. We just can't divide by zero :) It is in this sense that, per your remark "we always get the same value" -- $\mathrm{d}\tau=0$ all along the worldline of light, hence we can't use $\tau$ to parameterize it. We have to use some other function that's  monotonically increasing(/decreasing) along the worldline.
